# Only allowing scrolling up in a Table View?

Tags: swift, uitableview, scroll

Is there a way to make it so the user can only scroll up in a table view? Right now I only see an option to scroll both up and down.

Comment: you can scroll up and down on a tableview

Comment: i mean only able to scroll up. no scrolling down

Answer (score 0):

What does you mean under "scroll only up"?
If it's mean that content start from bottom and user can only scroll up, you can try this:

1) reverse array of objects that you use for feeding tableView

```
if shouldReverse {
    var reversed = myObjects.reverse()
    myObjects.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    myObjects.splice(reversed, atIndex: 0)
}
```

2) implement [scrollViewDidScroll:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll:) method from UIScrollViewDelegate protocol, and restrict content offset by it's y position

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if shouldReverse && scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldreverse is a unresolved identifier. contesnt doesnt start on the bottom. after the user goes through all the content, it automatically scrolls to the top and then i want to enabled scrolling up so the user can scroll up to refresh.